# Jenkins build summary link to post-build build summary

Tags: jenkins, artifacts, post-build

I have a job that is triggered as a post-build action for dozens of other jobs. It essentially organizes and process the artifacts of those upstream jobs (using Copy Artifact Plugin), and publishes the reformatted logs, and originals, as artifacts of its own.

I want the build summary pages of an upstream job to have a link to that downstream job. From what I gather, this is not an intended use case. Conventional wisdom seems to be that if we want a link to a downstream job, we should run it as a sub-project within the Build step of the upstream job. But if I do that, I don't have the artifacts to pass to the downstream job. Catch 22.

Or is there something (even something really hacky and nasty) I can do to make this work. People want to get the processed artifacts directly from the build page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way (and I think the only way) to do this would be to call the Jenkins api from the downstream job to put a link to itself in the upstream job's description. But this seemed like more work than it was worth. So we just didn't do anything, and we're all fine.